# Why does my selfMade HandleBars If-Condition not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, handlebars.js

Please help me!

My ifCond does not work:

The function:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
    if(v1 === v2) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

The HTML with handlebars:

```
            {{#each everyContext as |ActualContext|}}

              {{#ifCond ActualContext context}}
                <li class="active"><a href="./{{ActualContext}}.html#">!{{ActualContext}} </a></li>
              {{else}}
                <li><a href="./{{ActualContext}}.html#">{{ActualContext}}</a></li>
              {{/ifCond}}
            {{/each}}
```

Apparently something goes wrong in the  `{{#ifCond ActualContext context}}` part. These are definitely the same Strings. I am using this Data:

```
var data = {
        "allAttributes" : allAttributes.sort(),
        "viewTypes"     : viewDataTypes,
        "viewCategories": viewCategories,
        "context"       : context,
        "everyContext"  : everyContext
    };
```

The li class does NOT turn active at all.

Any ideas? Help me out please.

Comment: Can you log to console v1, v2 parameters in your ifCond helper? Are you sure that both of them of a type String? Not kind of "123" and 123

Comment: http://imgur.com/K2iMcxL @Dyrk